# How to find the right numpy `savetxt()` format?

Tags: numpy, string-formatting

Let's say I have this special data set:

```
a = np.asarray([[[1,2,3], 'austen', 'austen-emma'],
                [[4,5,6], 'austen', 'austen-sense']])
```

What will be the right `format` to call with to

```
np.savetxt(f, a, fmt=format)
```

I've tried `format=[[%d], %s, %s]` based on the function [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), but I still getting a TypeError. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you want the file to look like?  Does `%s; %s, %s`%tuple(a[0])` look right?  `savetxt` just iterates through your array and applies `format` to each row like that.

Comment: I wish that the file will save the data losslessly and will be able to restore it to the same numpy array afterward.

Comment: What exactly is the same array?  What `dtype`? `shape`?  How were you going to read it?  Does it have to be a text file (`csv`)?  Why not `np.save`, the binary numpy format?

Answer (score 2):

A simple %s should fix your issue, although you can specify more complicated formats as well, so the following code will work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[[1,2,3], 'austen', 'austen-emma'],
                 [[4,5,6], 'austen', 'austen-sense']])
np.savetxt("abc",a,fmt="%s")
```

why you are getting the error is because the default format is a **float** here with **%s** we are making the format to be a string.

Comment: Thank you, I'm guessing I will now encounter this problem now with `loadtxt()` what could be the right `dtype` there?

Comment: @limitless dtype="str" should fix it if you face any issues

Answer (score 1):

```
In [119]: a = np.asarray([[[1,2,3], 'austen', 'austen-emma'],
     ...:                  [[4,5,6], 'austen', 'austen-sense']])
     ...:                  
In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), 'austen', 'austen-emma'],
       [list([4, 5, 6]), 'austen', 'austen-sense']], dtype=object)
```

A copy-n-paste of your `a` produces an object dtype array.  It contains strings and lists.

We can specify a very general `%s` format:

```
In [121]: np.savetxt('test', a, fmt='%s, %s, %s')  # or fmt='%s',delimiter=','
In [122]: cat test
[1, 2, 3], austen, austen-emma
[4, 5, 6], austen, austen-sense
```

The result is the print representation of the lists, e.g. `str([1,2,3]` and the strings.

But the `csv` loaders will not be able to handle the list representation.

I could change the delimiter to ; so it isn't confused with the , in the list string:

```
In [128]: np.savetxt('test', a, fmt='%s', delimiter=';')
In [129]: cat test
[1, 2, 3];austen;austen-emma
[4, 5, 6];austen;austen-sense
In [130]: np.genfromtxt('test',delimiter=';', dtype=str)
Out[130]: 
array([['[1, 2, 3]', 'austen', 'austen-emma'],
       ['[4, 5, 6]', 'austen', 'austen-sense']], dtype='<U12')
```

Not bad - but the list has been loaded as a string.

One way or other, including lists in your array along with strings is going to give problems when loading.  There isn't a standardized format for `csv` that handles both lists and strings in the same line.  Normally `csv` has simple values, eg. numbers or strings, separated by a delimiter.  It does not define syntactic features like brackets.